# "this" doesn't resolve as expected when I put my jquery dom manipulation methods in to a namepsace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I've managed to avoid using namespace in most of my javascript dev to date, but I'm beginning to see the light through reading helpful articles like [this one](http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/)

I'm following Maeagers technique [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration) to create my namespace as shown below -

```
var newAndImproved = {

//div to put loaded content into
targetDiv: "",

//loads the initial content based on an anchor tag having a class named 'chosen'
loadInitialPage: function() {
    var chosenLink = $("#subnavigation a.chosen");
    newAndImproved.loadPartial(chosenLink);
},

loadPartial: function(clickedLink) {
    var theUrlToLoad = $(clickedLink).attr("href");
    $(newAndImproved.targetDiv).load(theUrlToLoad, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $(targetDiv).html(msg);
        }
    });
},

removeClassFromSubNav: function() {
    $("#subnavigation a").removeClass('chosen');
},

addChosenClassToNav: function(chosenLink) {
    $(chosenLink).addClass('chosen');
},

bindMethodsToNavigation: function() {
    $("#subnavigation a").bind('click', function(event) {
        var chosenLink = event.target;
        newAndImproved.removeClassFromSubNav();
        newAndImproved.loadPartial(chosenLink);
        newAndImproved.addChosenClassToNav(chosenLink);
        return false;
    });
}

};
```

I've called that namespace like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
newAndImproved.targetDiv = $("#subcontent");
newAndImproved.loadInitialPage();
newAndImproved.bindMethodsToNavigation();
});
```

I'm sure you've noticed that I'm referencing the namespace within itself rather than just using 'this'. I assume this is incorrect. But when I use 'this' the binding part will not work.

Strangely, the loadInitialPage method will work when using 'this'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rudie - a "namespace" is a contrivance, a pattern for using a Javascript object to segregate or organize functions. Because a namespace (defined according to the coding pattern illustrated above) is just an object, in fact there is a `this` in a "namespace".

Comment: Damn, you're right... I deleted my confusing comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `that` trick.  `this` gets re-assigned inside new scopes, including the anonymous function you are binding.

Consider this code:

```
function say(x){ alert(x); }

var myscope = {

    label : "myscope (toplevel)",

    func1 : function() {
        say("enter func1");
        var label = "inner func1";
        say("  this.label: " + this.label);
        say("  label: " + label);
    },

    func2 : function() {
        var label = "inner func2";
        say("enter func2");
        this.func1();
    }
};

myscope.func2();
```

If you run this, it will behave nicely, and the references to `this.xxx` all succeed as you would like.  However, if you add a func3 like this:

```
    func3 : function() {
        setTimeout( function(){
            var label = "anonymous func";
            say("enter anon func");
            this.func1();
        }, 2);
    }
```

...it will not work as you might imagine. Because the anonymous function is defined in no explicitly-specified scope, the `this` within it refers to the top level object, `window`. And there is no `func1` as a child of window (no top level object named `func1`).

For the same reason, the `this` within your anon function that you use in the call to `bind()` will fail.  In that case you can refer to the "namespace" object directly, or you can use a closure (some people call it "the `that` trick"):

```
    bindMethodsToNavigation: function() {
        var that = this;
        $("#subnavigation a").bind('click', function(event) {
            var chosenLink = event.target;
            that.removeClassFromSubNav();
            that.loadPartial(chosenLink);
            that.addChosenClassToNav(chosenLink);
            return false;
        });
    }
```

The `this` within the scope of `bindMethodsToNavigation` refers to `newAndImproved`.  The `this` within the anonymous function will refer to `window`.  Using a closure allows you to refer to the thing you want.  (*editorial comment*: I personally find the name `that` to be cute and entirely unhelpful. I like to use abbreviated names, in your case maybe something like `nai` to refer to `newAndImproved`)

Incidentally, you could also do this:

```
    clickHandler : function(event) {
        var chosenLink = event.target;
        this.removeClassFromSubNav();
        this.loadPartial(chosenLink);
        this.addChosenClassToNav(chosenLink);
        return false;
    },

    bindMethodsToNavigation: function() {
        $("#subnavigation a").bind('click', clickHandler);
    },
```

...and if they are both members of the `newAndImproved` object, then the `this` within `clickHandler` will be resolved to the `newAndImproved` object.  The key here is that `clickHandler` is not an anonymous, top-level function; it belongs to `newAndImproved` and when `this` is used within it, it resolves appropriately. Even more, you can just drop the use of `this` within `clickHandler`; it is not incorrect, but it is unnecessary. Some people like to add it for emphasis to those who might read the code later.

---

**EDIT**

One more note on this - on the decision whether to use anonymous functions or named functions as event handlers... Anon functions are so convenient and easy, and everybody uses them.  What I find is that in Firebug or the IE Javascript Debugger, when I look at a stack trace I get a loooong list of anon functions, and it's difficult to figure out just what the chain of functions is. Especially with AJAX and async handlers being fired in response to UI events, and so on. To provide some additional visibility at debug time, I sometimes use named functions (put into namespaces), and the callstack will show a few named fns along interspersed with a few anon fns. This sometimes helps. 
Just a small thing, though.

Comment: Thanks Cheeso, that works perfectly and is very well explained. As a side question, do you believe I should be wrapping this code into a separate namespace or should I just stick it all into the $(document).ready() ? I don't think I'll be reuse it at all. But one benefit I can see is that I can use the namespace to call the functions using firebugs console, where I couldn't do this when it's in the $(document).ready().

Comment: Hey I think it's a matter of preference and style. Javascript is pretty loose, and everyone seems to come up with their own conventions. Witness jQuery which is different from everything else. Personally I prefer to not clutter the toplevel scope with functions I will use once, so I tend toward using "namespace" type organization. Maybe Rudie would call me a namespace "fanboy."

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for namespaces at all. This looks like a very specific implementation (and not a reusable class). Wouldn't this be much simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var targetDiv = $("#subcontent"),
    loadInitialPage = function() {
        ...
    },
    loadPartial = function(clickedLink) {
        ...
    },
    removeClassFromSubNav: function() {
        ...
    },
    addChosenClassToNav = function(chosenLink) {
        ...
    },
    bindMethodsToNavigation = function() {
        ...
    };

    loadInitialPage();
    bindMethodsToNavigation();
});
```

Simpler because you can reference all functions without namespace now. No need for `this.` or `namespacename.`.

Why separate the namespace/function declarations from the `document.ready` stuff?

**edit**
[You should read this.](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/) It's more than a few lines, but it's very readable and very useful.

**edit**
It's alright to put a lot of stuff in `document.ready`, because that's only executed once.

Comment: True, given the simple scenario, there's no real benefit to having a namespace. However, imagine he defines distinct UI logic packages; one might be simplistic and one might be more sophisticated. In that case you'd like to have multiple objects segregating those things. What I'm saying is, it's possible to imagine a case where namespace might be useful, even in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I think every library should have 1 namespace, but more than that is just pretentious, unnecessary and less readable IMO. When I make a new class, I put it in my personal or my app's namespace. Most functions I make (by far) are very specific implementations of those classes, so they don't have to be namespaced. **edit** I think in the end it all boils down to readability: whatever you want. In performance it matters so little (with JS engines these days).

Comment: @Rudie - I agree with your comment that that there's probably no need for a name space in the code I provided and to date I've avoided doing so in simple cases. However, I'd assumed I was not using best practices by avoiding a namespace. I may have to go back to basics and look at when and where I should use them.

Comment: I think that's probably smart. Even namespace fanboys won't use them all the time. Personally, I use them rarely in JS. I do however make use of JS flexibility: A function is a function, an object, a namespace and a class. Sometimes that's very good to know =)

Comment: Due to that flexibility, does that mean that in my above example I've created an object called 'newAndImproved'? I assume it is, both your and Cheeso's previous comments seem to be saying so. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. `newAndImproved` is an object. `jQuery` is a good example. `jQuery` is a function (`jQuery('a.foo')`) and a namespace (`jQuery.settings.bar`) and a class (`new jQuery(Sizzle('a.foo'))` and it's an object because everything in JS is.